# I have some $\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{z}(1-\frac{i}{2})^{-1}-\frac{1}{z}(1+\frac{i}{2})^{-1}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

For my Radius of convergence, I have that
$|\frac{i}{2}| < 1 \Longrightarrow |z| >1$. Is this a valid radius of convergence?

Comment: What you wrote after "After partial fraction, I have some" is not true at all. The partial fraction decomposition is $$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{1 + iz}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{1 - iz}}.
$$

Comment: @Gary do you know why I could just use $(-z^2)$ and represent it as a geometric series instead of using partial fractions?

Comment: It is true that $$
\frac{1}{{1 - w}} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {w^n } 
$$ for *any* complex number $w$, such that $|w|<1$. If $|z|<1$ then $-z^2$ is a complex number whose modulus is less than $1$. Thus you can employ the geometric series with $w:=-z^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z|<1$, then$$\frac1{1+z^2}=1-z^2+z^4-z^6+\cdots,$$and this series diverges if $|z|\geqslant1$. So, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Do we also get $R=1$ from $|-z^2|< 1 \Longrightarrow |z^2| < 1 \Longrightarrow |z|<1$?

Comment: Yes, as long as you add that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ converges and its sum is $\frac1{1-z}$ if $|z|<1$ and that it diverges otherwise.